# how to run native video player on android using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android

Is is possible to launch android native player from web browser click on button or link?
I don't want to play it using html5 video tag inside the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebView` for that. Here is a code sample to show toast from web page.

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } }
```

Bind the above class to the JavaScript that runs in your `WebView` with `addJavascriptInterface()`

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)